# Post apocalypse book where a Scottish highlands chief takes charge

Tags: story-identification, books

Mid to late eighties book from a UK library.

It begins as society is approaching breakdown, a heredity highlands chieftain is visiting the Glencoe Massacre monument and also mentally working out a plan for the future. Whilst he is in Glencoe at the start of the story he meets a "Bonnie lassie" and tells her that "she has this day met The McGregor".

Society collapses (maybe nuclear war too but I'm not sure?) and he ends up on a Outer Hebrides island. Slowly he uses his position with other clansmen to gain real power and finally he's got the authority to order men hanged or outcast.

Other small scale survivor groups establish trading contracts with his group but they eventually have to swear fealty to him.

I think there's a battle with fleets of fishing vessels and shotguns as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me a bit like '[The Inferno](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Inferno.html?id=sM2_CQAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)' by Fred and Geoffrey Hoyle

> "Cameron, a tall, testy, whisky-drinking, nationalist-minded, Scottish physicist, may not have been an astronomer, but he knew the off things in the sky when he saw them. From an Australian mountaintop where he was advising on the location of a radiotelescope he saw what looked like Mars, in the wrong spot in the sky. But it wasn't Mars at all, it was a supernova ... no, not a supernova but a quasar.
>
> Knowing what would happen, Cameron dashed home to Scotland and found himself at a crossroads of his life. In the face of total catastrophe, and of intense heat, darkness and rain, he took over as natural leader with both the north and south of the United Kingdom turning to him for help."

Comment: Yep! That's the book I was looking for. My memory failed with the protagonist's name, I thought it was McGregor but as soon as I saw 'Cameron' that clinched it. Cheers